# How to replace all instances of an HTML element with a variable (Or easier method)

Tags: javascript, html

I have an HTML snippet that I have repeated text all throughout and would like to be able to set a single variable and have the document be updated to show the text where I have placeholders. The HTML does not have any body, head, etc tags as this will be a child section of a much larger webpage.

I can also use any simpler/easier ways to accomplish this if anyone knows of any, but if not, preferably a solution using only JavaScript would be great.

The current issue is that by using "document.getElementById()", it will only replace the first instance of the element, which is doing exactly what it's supposed to do, but I need a solution that will replace all instances.

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    var Name = "Some Name";
    var WebAddress = "https://example.com";
    window.onload = function Placeholder() {
        document.getElementById('Placeholder-Name').innerHTML = Name;
        document.getElementById('Placeholder-WebAddress').innerHTML = WebAddress;
        document.getElementById('Placeholder-WebAddress-href').href = WebAddress;
    }
</script>
<h1><placeholder id="Placeholder-Name"></placeholder></h1>

<p>
    Blah blah blah<a id="Placeholder-WebAddress-href" href="#"><placeholder id="Placeholder-WebAddress"></placeholder></a> blah blah blah <placeholder id="Placeholder-WebAddress"></placeholder>.
    And some more blah <placeholder id="Placeholder-WebAddress"></placeholder>.
</p>
```

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('.class-name')` will get you all instances of elements that match that class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.querySelectorAll()` is the method you should use, not `document.getElementsByClassName()` because it returns a Live Collection which under certain circumstances result in unexpected values. Most importantly, once you get a collection of tags you must iterate through each one using an array method or a loop.

Details can be found in comments and the content of demo (i.e. read *everything*).

```js
/** insStr()
@Param: selector [string]...........: CSS syntax to target tags
        string [string].............: Text content or attribute value
        attribute [string](optional): Name of attribute to modify
This function will insert a string into a given group of tags, either as text content or an 
attribute value.
//A - Pass a selector, a string for text in between the tags.
      If it's for an attribute then add it as third parameter
//B - Collect all tags that match selector
      '#ID' -- '.CLASS' -- '[ATTRIBUTE=VALUE]' -- 'TAGNAME'
      This collection is called a NodeList
//C - Iterate through the NodeList in a for...of loop
//D - if the third parameter exists, set string as the value
//E - otherwise set string as text content
*/
function insStr(selector, string, attribute = null) { //A
  const nodes = document.querySelectorAll(selector); //B  
  for (let node of nodes) { //C
    if (attribute) {
      node.setAttribute(attribute, string); //D
    } else {
      node.textContent = string; //E
    }
  }
  return false;
}

insStr('#main-title', `Prefix Ids with a Hash: #. Also IDS MUST BE UNIQUE! NEVER DUPLICATE AN ID!!!`);

insStr('.content', `Prefix class with a dot: .`);

insStr('[name=field]', `If there's no id or class, try any attribute/value an element has and wrap it in brackets: [...] 
-- Also note that the third parameter is setting the value attribute`, 'value');

insStr('a', `If the element is totally void of any usable attribute/value you can use the tagName -- ex. 'a' for <a>`);

insStr('a', `https://stackoverflow.com`, 'href');

insStr('article', `BTW there's no such thing as <placeholder> tag -- it's not standard. Follow standards else it'll come back and bite you in the arse`);
```

```css
input {
  display: block;
  width: 99%;
}
```

```html
<h1 id='main-title'></h1>
<p class='content'></p>
<p class='content'></p>
<p class='content'></p>
<p class='content'></p>
<input name='field'><br>
<a href=''></a><br>
<a href=''></a><br>
<a href=''></a><br>
<a href=''></a><br><br>
<article></article>
```

Comment: thankyou thankyou, i've found so many wordy explanations of solutions that are hard to follow. But this code just works and straight forward!

Answer (score 0):

When you have an ID, there is only one element that can have that ID. Instead what you want to do is assign each of these elements with a class name. Then you can call

`document.getElementsByClassName('placeholderclass')`

which will return an array of elements with that class name. To assign the same variable to each of them use a for loop to iterate over them and assign your desired values.

Answer (score 0):

The ID should be reserved for HTML elements that are unique. Generally you're not going to want to have more than one element with a specific ID.

Since you're going to have multiple instances of these elements on your page, you should try using "class" instead of "id" in your HTML elements. You can then use the javascript method "document.getElementsByClassName(classname)" to select these elements and change them all at once.

Example:

```
<a class="placeholder-webaddress-href" href="#">Example</a>
```

Can be selected with

```
document.getElementsByClassName("placeholder-webaddress-href")
```

Answer (score 0):

IDs are meant for unique HTML elements, so there's no plural selector for them.

getElement**s**ByClassName or querySelectorAll (my favorite) will do it for you.

(While answering this I learned you can't use `.forEach` with getElementsByClassName. Huh.)

[image: Demonstrating getElementsByClassName]

Answer (score -3):

`document.getElementById()` is no longer used, check for `querySelector()` or `querySelectorAll()` in your case

https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll

Comment: `document.getElementById() is no longer used` - er, what? Do you have a source for this bold statement? (If you do, I'll remove my downvote, but I can't see it, millions of webpages will break if `document.getElementById` stops working...)

Comment: It's still working but it's old and `querySelector()` is more recent and it allows to do multiple selection ^^. It's like `let` instead of `var` sorry I misspoke.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using `getElementById()` if you want to select one element by its id.